# returning middle element in stack

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, linked-list

I have to create a method peek MidElement , so as return the middle element of the stack . 
So do I have to use an ArrayList, or TORTOISE-HARE algo .

The following is my Class , which has a method named `peekMidElement`.
How do I reference `Size()` to the `ArrayList` . 
When I compile the following , I am getting IndexOutOFBoundsExcption at `ArrayList.RangeCheck(UnknownSource)` & at `ArrayList.get(UnknownSource)`

```
public class SortableStack<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ISortableStack<E> {  
        private int N;            
        private Node first;       
    private ArrayList<E> listOne = new ArrayList<E>(); 
    /* I have to reference the Stack to array list 
      which I am going use for finding the size of the stack */

    public boolean isEmpty() {  
            return first == null;  
        }  

        public int size() {  
            return N;  
        }  


    public E peekMidElement() {  
        if(listOne.size() <= 0){  
        throw new EmptyStackException();  
        }  

        return listOne.get(listOne.size()/2);  
     }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this for both Java and JavaScript?

Comment: Dont know . I've had these problems Before ...

Comment: @Yonathan- Is this for a class?  Many people have posted questions along these lines.  If this is a homework question, please mark it with the homework tag, since it's just dishonest otherwise.

Comment: what's with the random caps and symbols?

Comment: The value of `N` doesn't change from `null`. You can't refer to an array element `null`. You'll get an error if you do. Also you can't divide `null` by 2 (`null instanceof Object` is false).

Comment: Actually you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, and it's not while you are compiling since it's an exception... thus you should provide the code that calls your class... Btw your code seems weird to me... i don't see anything that can throw this exception, and it seems you are trying to use generics while you know the items in your list will gona be nodes (???) Give us the complete stack

Comment: @fireshadow52 - that is nonsense.  `N` is an `int`, and has a default value of zero, not null.  In Java, a variable whose type is a primitive type can NEVER be null.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how the code snippet you gave can throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsExcption` at the point you have indicated.  I conclude that:

- the code snippet is not the actual code (e.g. it has been spliced together from a larger class, leaving out some crucial details), or
- the exception is not thrown at the place you indicated, or
- ... this class (which is not thread-safe) is being used in a multi-threaded application without adequate synchronization.  The scenario is that some other thread deletes a bunch of elements from `listOne` at exactly the wrong moment.  This unlikely, and if it was the cause, the failure would only occur *very occasionally*.